# PHPExcel two collors in one cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to add more than one color to the cell on **PHPExcel**.

Now I'm adding cell with this:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue("A1", $text);
```

Found this, but doesn't work:

```
$RichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
```

Probably it something easy, just I didn't find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at section 4.6.37 of the developer documentation describing rich text, and also the 05featuredemo.inc.php example in /Tests which demonstrates using rich text in a cell

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$run1 = $objRichText->createTextRun('RED ');
$run1->getFont()->setColor( new PHPExcel_Style_Color( PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_RED ) );

$run2 = $objRichText->createTextRun('BLUE ');
$run2->getFont()->setColor( new PHPExcel_Style_Color( PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_BLUE ) );

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue("A1", $objRichText);
```

Comment: Thank you. I hope that it something simple :)